# Is it possible to plot a statistical time series with dates in Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a statistical time series using Seaborn but I can't seem to figure it out. I've tried using both the `lmplot` and `tsplot` methods but am obviously missing something key.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as pylab

p = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": pd.date_range('1/1/2015', periods = 12),
    "values":range(1,13)
})

# Regular Matplotlib  (via pandas) works
p.plot(x = "date", style = 'o--')

# Can't get lmplot to work
sns.lmplot(x = "date", y = "values", data = p)

# Can't get tsplot to work either
sns.tsplot(time = "date", value = "values", data = p)
```

Comment: In general, I don't think any of the seaborn plots handle timestamps very well. Better to stick with plotting in matplotlib directly or via pandas as you do here.

Comment: Further, the `tsplot` function in seaborn is not designed to just make a time series. It is designed for the case where you have multiple values for each timestep, for which it computes the average and confidence interval. See the examples http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/timeseries_plots.html

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Hopefully the Seaborn package gets more functionality but for the time being I'll stop ripping my hair out.

Comment: The pandas DataFrame plotting methods will handle this case perfectly well, there isn't anything extra seaborn would be able to do for this plot anyway.

Comment: There is. I want a a regression andconfidence interval. By comparison ggplot can handle this situation quite easily but it seems that it wouldn't be as straightforward in Pandas at the moment

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I can't add this as a comment as I'm not rated high enough.

I've been battling through timeseries recently, and the following SO post is pretty much exactly the same as yours, with the same question about confidence intervals:

[Plotting time-series data with seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795348/plotting-time-series-data-with-seaborn)