# tsplot out of bounds error in Python seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

i'm trying to plot time series data as points in seaborn, colored by condition. i tried the following:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({"t": [0, 1],
                       "y": [1, 1],
                       "c": ["A", "B"]})
colors = {"A": "r", "B": "g"}
fig = plt.figure()
# this fails
sns.tsplot(time="t", value="y", condition="c", unit="c",
           data=df, err_style="unit_points", interpolate=False,
           color=colors)
plt.show()
```

the error is:

```
x_diff = x[1] - x[0]
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

however if i plot the data as:

```
# this works
sns.pointplot(x="t", y="y", hue="c", join=False, data=df)
```

then it works. `pointplot` treats time as categorical data though which is not right for this. how can this be done with `tsplot`? it should give the same result as `pointplot` except the x-axis (`t`) should scale quantitatively like time and not as categorical.

**update**

here's a revised example that shows `tsplot` fails even when there are multiple observations for most of the labels. in this df 2 out of 3 conditions have multiple observations, but 1 condition that doesn't is enough to cause the error:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"t": [0, 1.1, 2.9, 3.5, 4.5, 5.9],
                       "y": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                       "c": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"]})
colors = {"A": "r", "B": "g", "C": "k"}
print df
fig = plt.figure()
# this works but time axis is wrong
#sns.pointplot(x="t", y="y", hue="c", join=False, data=df)

# this fails
sns.tsplot(time="t", value="y", condition="c", unit="c",
           data=df, err_style="unit_points", interpolate=False,
           color=colors)
plt.show()
```

@mwaskom suggested making ordinary plot. doing that manually is difficult is error prone and duplicates work that seaborn already does. seaborn already has a way to plot and facet data by various features in dataframes and i don't want to reproduce this code. here's a way to do manually which is cumbersome:

```
# solution using plt.subplot
# cumbersome and error prone solution
# the use of 'set' makes the order non-deterministic
for l in set(df["c"]):
    subset = df[df["c"] == l] 
    plt.plot(subset["t"], subset["y"], "o", color=colors[l], label=l)
```

basically i am looking for something like `sns.pointplot` that uses numeric, rather than categorical x-axis. does seaborn have something like this? another way to think of it is as a dataframe aware version of `plt.scatter` or `plt.plot`.

Comment: In matplotlib 1.5, `plt.scatter` and `plt.plot` are [dataframe aware](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/users/whats_new.html#working-with-labeled-data-like-pandas-dataframes)

Comment: Also your data are not likely to work with `tsplot` even if you add more timepoints, because your observations are not nested within your sampling units. This is described in [the docs](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.tsplot.html) and [on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795348/plotting-time-series-data-with-seaborn/22798911#22798911).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem really is that you have too few observations.  2 observations for 2 conditions means there will be only 1 observation for each condition.  For a time-series plot, this is probably not going to work.  `x_diff = x[1] - x[0]` calculates the time interval length and can't work with just one observation per group.

If you have more than 1 observation per group, i.e.:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"t": [0, 1, 2, 3],
                       "y": [1, 1, 2, 4],
                       "c": ["A", "B", "A", "B"]})
```

it should plot just fine.

Comment: some time series have only one observation per group. if tsplot can't handle this how can i get a plot of points by condition, with x axis being interpreted numerically and not categorically as in pointplot? is there another function?

Comment: Just draw a regular plot? Based on the question, you just want points at two different values of the x variable.

Comment: @mwaskom but I want seaborn to automatically color them by condition, reading from the dataframe. I don't want to do this manually with ``plt.plot``. usually the time series have way more than one observation per condition but there are edge cases where there is only one per condition

Comment: @mwaskom: i updated my question to be clearer and gave a specific example

Comment: @CT Zhu: it turns out you need more than one observation *for every* group see my updated question