# how to make a seaborn uncertainty time series plot with a 3d array

Tags: python, csv, seaborn

3d random array is generated as follows:

```
import numpy as np    
SPN = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (100, 31, 3))
```

Dimension "3" is for categories "A", "B", "C", and should be named in the legend.

Now I would like to use `SPN` to make a seaborn-like plot as it shows here:

[Plotting time-series data with seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795348/plotting-time-series-data-with-seaborn)

The example plot:
[image: the example plot]

Comment: You will have multiples time series per category, do you just want to average across all datapoints along each category A, B, C?

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for your feedback. I wanted to have an average, percentile 15% and 85% for each category. The average line is a solid line, and the range between 15% and 85% should be a tranparent colored region like the example show.