# Python: Storing values in a 3D array to csv

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

I have the follwoing problem. I have a 3D array like 
`matrix = np.zeros((30,30,100))` where every entry is a coordinate and gets a value. So `matrix [0][0][0]` is the coordinate x=0,y0,z=0 and has a value of 0. Now i want to store all the values in a csv like this where the first 3 rows are the coordinates and the 4th the corresponding value:

[image]

Is there a fast way with numpy to do this?

Comment: where does your corresponding value come from?

Comment: They are stored in another process, but for this example it's also ok to store only zeros.

Comment: Does it have to be a csv file? I have found that np.save is more useful for saving ND arrays in numpy.

Comment: I think numpy.savetxt do the same. As long it has the structure like above, it's ok

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use pandas, it can both reshape the array and save it as csv.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# create an example array
a = np.arange(24).reshape([2,3,4])
# convert it to stacked format using Pandas
stacked = pd.Panel(a.swapaxes(1,2)).to_frame().stack().reset_index()
stacked.columns = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'value']
# save to disk
stacked.to_csv('stacked.csv', index=False)
```

Otherwise, you can apply

```
np.ravel()
```

to your array and then restore indices using one of the recipes [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46134827/).

Comment: Panel is outdated.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you get the coordinates with the indices:

```
def iter_3D(matrix):
    for i in range(matrix.shape[0]):
        for j in range(matrix.shape[1]):
            for k in range(matrix.shape[2]):
                yield i, j, k

l = []

for i, j, k in iter_3D(matrix):
    l.append('%d %d %d %d' %(str(indices_x(i, j, k)), str(indices_y(i, j, k)), str(indices_z(i, j, k)), str(matrix[i, j, k]))

with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(l))
```

More sophisticated solutions are possible, but this should be the core. Have a look at: [csv io](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) in the python docs or [nditer](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html) if you want a more sophisticated iteration method or use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) (takes a little time to get the hang out of it).