# Seaborn timeseries plot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, time-series, seaborn

I've cleaned a dataset and reached a point where my pandas dataframe looks like:

```
aggregated_df = another_df.groupby(['datetime_x', 'my_category'])['my_value'].mean()
aggregated_df.head(3)

datetime_x  my_category
2011-10-01  foo         2090.91
2011-12-22  bar         2545.45
2012-01-06  foo         1944.44
Name: my_value, dtype: float64
```

When I try to generate a plot with multiple timeseries all together (each one representing one of the `my_category` fields) I get: `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`

```
sns.tsplot(
    data=aggregated_df, 
    time="datetime_x", 
    value="my_value",
    condition="my_category",
)
```

I think the reason is because each category, when seen as a pandas Series array, may have a different length than the others. Perhaps because some dates are missing, but I am not sure this is the reason, and I find it very strange if that is the case.

I also set the `condition=` parameter for the seaborn `tsplot` method to what I believe should be the place for the "categorical variable" (in my case the `my_category` column), but it may be I am misunderstanding how to use `tsplot`.

Also, the effect of `groupby` is that I get a pandas `MultiIndex` with nested `levels`, but I am not sure this is the format seaborn expects, even though it looks good to me as I am trying to plot multiple timeseries labelled by one of the columns (`my_category`).

What am I doing wrong?
How can I plot multiple timeseries on the same graph each one labelled from the categorical column?

Comment: `aggregated_df` isn't a `DataFrame`, it's a `Series`.

Comment: perhaps `aggregated_df.reset_index()` to convert it to `DataFrame`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tsplot` needs that the "time" is the same for each condition, i.e. for each condition, you need the data is sampled at the same time units.

Take a look at the structure of the data frame in this example from the tsplot docstring, this will make it a bit more clear:

```
gammas = sns.load_dataset("gammas")
ax = sns.tsplot(time="timepoint", value="BOLD signal",
                unit="subject", condition="ROI",
                data=gammas)
```

I'm afraid, that the `tsplot` will not be helpful for you in this case.

This answer might be helpful to you, for a nice combination of matplotlib and pandas to get tsplot-like behaviour: [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22795348/6151948)

Comment: what is gammas dataset? I can't find any description about this dataset

Comment: @VuAnh, this is a standard dataset, you can find the full description on: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/blob/master/gammas.csv

Comment: thanks for your quick response. I have already check this csv file. And the code for loading it https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/blob/master/process/gammas.py. My question is what is description of dataset? Whats data point represent? For example, in case of titanic dataset, I can find the full description of it here https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/data